# Is Stream.close() a terminal operation?

Tags: java, api, java-stream

Each method in `Stream` and `BaseStream` neatly specifies if the operation is intermediate or (short-circuiting) terminal.

The exception is the `close()` method which only states that close handlers be called.

I'm assuming that `close()` is a terminal operation and that invoking other methods will result in an `IllegalStateException`. However, as it stands it seems to be up to the implementation to decide this.

Is this omission in the Javadoc an oversight or is this deliberate and am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that `Stream.close()` can be considered as a *terminal* operation.  *An operation in a stream pipeline that takes a stream as input and produces a result or side-effect. After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered consumed, and can no longer be used.*

Now if you check the implementation of the close() operation, it is as follows:

```
public void close() {
    linkedOrConsumed = true; // it sets the flag consumed as true
```

And now if you try to access the stream say using a map operation, you are going to get an IllegalStateException as there are checks during the construction process of ReferencePipelines.

```
    if (previousStage.linkedOrConsumed)
        throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_STREAM_LINKED);
```

Try with the following code:

```
    Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(myStringNumbers); 
    stream.close();
    List<Integer> list1 = stream.map(Integer::parseInt).collect(toList());
```

The above code will throw `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: It was incomplete. Sorry for the delay in completing it.

Answer (score 4):

`Stream.close()` is neither, an intermediate operation nor a terminal operation. It isn’t actually an operation (in the sense of the Stream API) at all. Recall that after invoking a terminal operation, you are not allowed to invoke another operation on the same stream.

However, it is not only allowed but the *intended* use of `close()` to be invoked on a `Stream` *after* the terminal operation, so it isn’t a stream operation of that kind. The action of closing the stream has the same property as terminal operations of forbidding follow-up operations on the Stream (in case they weren’t already forbidden due to a commenced terminal operation) and that’s admittedly a bit underspecified.

But on the other hand, it’s the normal behavior of a `close` operation of making a resource or object unusable for follow-up operations, so it shouldn’t come at a surprise that this also holds for Streams.

In practice, the [well-known error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stream+has+already+been+operated+upon+or+closed) speaks for itself as it names “*has been operated upon*” or “*closed*” as two equal reasons for rejecting follow-up operations.